# Loading ehcache during project startup/Jvm Start up

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, ehcache

I am trying to connect a tool from load method so that can retrieve data and put inside ehcache.The problem m facing is `@Autowiring` is not working inside `MyBootstrapCacheLoaderFactory` nor inside any other class(getting called from load method). I will be gratified if anyone can provide some solution.Creating Each and every instance is not possible nor its helping with some services..Thanks in advance.

```
@Component  
public class TestingBootstrapCacheLoaderFactory extends BootstrapCacheLoaderFactory implements BootstrapCacheLoader{

@Autowired
 Services service;

@Override
public BootstrapCacheLoader createBootstrapCacheLoader(Properties properties) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return new MyBootstrapCacheLoaderFactory();
}

@Override
public Object clone() throws CloneNotSupportedException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return super.clone();
}
public boolean isAsynchronous() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return false;
}
public void load(Ehcache myCache) throws CacheException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    System.out.println("load your cache with whatever you want....");
    service.connect(); //null pointer as autowired doesnt work
    //nor it is working if i create a class object here and try to user 
    //other class for autowiring
}
```

Comment: an `@Autowired` field cannot be `null` if that would be the application will fail to start. You are probably creating a new instance of the `TestingBootstrapCacheLoaderFactory` instead of letting spring create the instance.

Comment: Hi @M.Deinum Thanks for reply.As you know TestingBootstrapCacheLoaderFactory gets called at the time of jvm startup.This is exact code which i have written and throws nullpointer if i try to catch exception.I tried creating enviornment instance using autowire and same issue m facing .environement.getproperty throws null pointer.Yaa want to confirm my application is starting.I tried solution from this link http://forums.terracotta.org/forums/posts/list/4335.page but this is nt working for me

Comment: If i will try to create @Autowired Environment env in this class then env will be null.

Comment: Ofcourse it is null because it isn't a spring managed bean... How can spring inject something into something it doesn't control/own.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Giving @Postconstruct annotation above my method worked for me

Comment: Can you detail a little? How did this help? and what does your PostConstruct method look like? also your createBootstrapCacheLoader() returns a different class. Can you please detail on what this class has. I am also facing the same issue as I am trying to call a JPA interface method from the BootstrapLoader.